# How to execute AT commands into the serial port in java?

Tags: java, java-me

I have device which connected to the modem using a serial port, which has two SIMs. I have received a requirement to get the IMSI number of these SIMs from the modem. I heard it can be retrieved by giving the AT command "AT+CIMI" to the modem. My question are:

- How is the AT command given to the modem
- if it is possible to retrieve the IMSI number in any other way.
- Are there any libraries to execute the the AT commands

Answer (score 0):

JNI.

At least it was when I did it 10 years ago.

Hopefully there is now an actual library for accessing serial ports :-/